# Using Stream Writer To Write a data in the text file but how to format it

Tags: c#

```
Names               Date               Time
Sandra              11/18/2013         10.12AM
Denise              12/21/2013         10.10PM
Prnikshenth         11/11/2019         12.00AM
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
class FunWithScheduling
{
       public void AddView()
       {
                  FileStream s = new FieStream("Scheduler.txt",FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write);
                  StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(s);
                  Console.WriteLine("Enter the Name of the Person To Be Met:");
                  string name = Console.ReadLine();
                  w.Write(name);
                  w.Flush();
                  w.Close();
                  s.Close();
       }
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           FunWithScheduling a = new FunWithScheduling();
           a.AddView();
       } 
}
```

I used this code to add a name but it gets stored like this

```
Names               Date               Time
Sandra              11/18/2013         10.12AM
Denise              12/21/2013         10.10PM
Prnikshenth         11/11/2019         12.00AMShawn
```

I added Shawn but this is how it gets stuck with the time.

Comment: Whatever program wrote that file forgot to use WriteLine() and used Write() instead.  There's a pretty good candidate for that program visible in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write to a new line before. I've also adding `using` statements so you don't have to call `close` manually.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"Scheduler.txt"))
{
   sw.Write(Environment.NewLine + name);
}
```

Comment: How about not opening the stream explicitly and writing `File.WriteAllText("\n"+name);` Or `using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(filename))`. Makes things much simpler.

Comment: You'd have to do `File.ReadAllText` first and prepend that variable otherwise `File.WriteAllText("\n"+name")` would overwrite it. But both could work, updated the answer.

Comment: I meant `File.AppendAllText`. Blame it on Saturday.

Comment: Haha, it happens :) You were right, both methods are clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following solution which might help

```
string line = name + "\t" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString() + "\t" + DateTime.Now.Time.ToString();

w.WriteLine(line );
```

You might just need to check the formatting of the Date and Time respectively.

Comment: DateTime.Now.Time.ToString();

Comment: DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();